# Auto populate recipients in DocuSign Envelope using custom button (SFDC Lightning)

Tags: lightning, custom-button, docusign

We have a custom object called "Legal Contracts" and we have DocuSign linked to it. I need to customize a custom button so that it auto populates the DocuSign Envelope's Recipient section using the contact information from a lookup field in the custom object.

a. **Lookup field:** Customer_Signed_By_LC__c

b. **Email API from Lookup field:** Customer_Signed_By_LC__r.Email

c. **Contact ID from Lookupfield:** Customer_Signed_By_LC__r.Id

d. **Current "working" custom button:**

```
{!IF( Legal_Contract__c.Parent_Company_LC__c = "Company A", 

URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000ANysEAG"]) 

, 

URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000ANysEAG"]) 

)}
```

The following Link gives a good overview (see section: Custom Recipient List (Individuals)) on how to achieve this:
https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-customize-envelope-contacts

I updated my code following directions from the link, but I'm getting a Syntax error.

> Error: Syntax error. Missing '

New code:

```
{!IF( Legal_Contract__c.Parent_Company_LC__c = "Company A", 

URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000ANysEAG",
CRL = 'Email~'+encodeURIComponent('{!Legal_Contract__c.Client_s_Email__c};Role~Signer 2
]) 

, 

URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000ANysEAG",
CRL = 'Email~'+encodeURIComponent('{!Legal_Contract__c.Client_s_Email__c};Role~Signer 2
]) 

)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing single quote and closing parenthesis on `encodeURIComponent` where you have `CRL=....`

The `encodeURIComponent` should be closed, and should look like as below. Observe the closing `')`.

```
CRL = 'EMail~' + encodeURIComponent('{!Legal_Contract__c.Client_s_Email__c};Role~Signer 2')
```

---

While the answer is specific to the syntax error you are receiving, but I don't think you can use this JS function in a formula/custom button. The documentation link that you have provided in the question does not clearly specify where does this need to be configured. You may like to check with DocuSign support as well for further details.

If you want to encode the URL, you will need to use `URLENCODE(..)` here. Something as:

```
URLENCODE('{!Legal_Contract__c.Client_s_Email__c};Role~Signer 2')
```

Comment: I got a different error with that. "Error: Unknown function encodeURIComponent. Check spelling."

Comment: I didn't notice that you are using this in a formula field, I was looking more at the syntax. I don't think you can actually utilize this JS function in a formula field. The documentation in the link is not very clear as where can you create it. You may additionally like to check with DocuSign support on the implementation.

Comment: I'm using this in a custom button. I changed the email field from formula text to email type and got the same error thought `URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Legal_Contract__c.Id,ecId="a1Kn0000000ANysEAG",
CRL = 'EMail~' + encodeURIComponent('{!Legal_Contract__c.Customer_s_Email__c};Role~Signer 2')
]) `

Comment: As I mentioned, `enodeURIComponent` is a JS function, and that you cannot possibly use JS functions directly in a custom button/formula field. You may need to use `URLENCODE()` here. I have updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the article referenced "Customize Envelope Contacts"  has moved to https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=psy1581360698967&topicId=jba1581360655134.html&_LANG=enus

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.