# How to add a second recipient to a DocuSign Button?

Tags: docusign

I am trying to create a DocuSign button that sends to two recipients. One is the contact and one is the User's manager.

I am able to create the button with the contact, however, I am unable to figure out how to add a manager  of the user as a second recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Mileage may vary depending on the package version of DS, but you could try this (let us know if it fails in your testing):

```
CRL = 'Email~' + Contact.Email+ ';LastName~'+ Contact.LastName +';Role~Signer 1;,Email~'+ User.Manager.Email+ ';LastName~'+ User.Manager.LastName + ';Role~Signer 2',
```

If that doesnt work here is a slightly different example citing version 7.0 that you could get inspiration from:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/268386/10073
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250220/10073